# Синхронизация аккаунтов между сайтами wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Есть два сайта на wordpress как синхронизировать аккаунты между ними?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress предлагает для этого специальное решение - multisite. [Здесь](https://wpmag.ru/2014/wordpress-multisite/) можно почитать более подробно о том когда стоит, и когда не стоит его использовать.

Аккаунты пользователей могут быть едиными для использования на всех сайтах сети.